# Projecting negative coordinates inside display area

Tags: omnet++, inet

I am testing the RandomWaypointMobility with a constrained area `minX=-3000m, maxX=3000m, minY=-3000m and maxY=3000m`. The `@display`strings sets `bgp=6000,6000`. The result is that nodes in the negative part of the coordinate system are rendered outside the display/canvas area.

Are there some parameters I can use to tell OMNeT++/INET that origo for the coordinate system is at the center of the display/canvas? I have tried

```
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMaxX = 3000m
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMinX = -3000m
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMaxY = 3000m
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMinY = -3000m
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMaxZ = 3000m
*.visualizer.sceneVisualizer.sceneMinZ = -3000m
```

but it doesn't work as I hoped for.

I realize that for RandomWaypointMobility I can just use a constrained area with positive coordinates only, which would keep objects within the canvas. However, my next task is to pull in mobility traces that include negative coordinates. Do I need to manually shift all coordinates so they become positive and stay within the canvas/display, or is there a smarter  way of doing things?

Any hints appreciated!

Thanks,
Dragos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you set is in fact `bgb=6000,6000` which sets the size of the module. There were indeed plans to add a tag called `bgp` directly into OMNeT++ which would introduce an offset, but at the end it was not implemented. The reason is that once you go down into that rabbit hole, you want to implement also scaling and then rotation etc. So the default display string based visualization left as simple as possible and all these transformation stuff was left for the model code.

So indeed, `SceneCanvasVisualizer` in INET has a `viewScale` and `viewTranslation` parameter that can be used for these purposes.

Comment: Thanks, `viewTranslation`was exactly what I needed!

Comment: As you are new here on SO.... You should accept an answer if that answers your question so other people who are looking for the same question will have an easier time finding it.

Comment: @Rudy Please let me know how to accept the answer, and I'll be happy to do it. I can only see upvote/downvote arrows at the top of the question and stackoverflow tells me I don't have enough "karma" to upvote.

Comment: @Rudy Sorry, I feel really stupid now after seeing the link you sent. Thanks for the help both with OMNeT++ and StackOverflow